# localStorage.setItem string base64 change char '+' to '&amp;#x2B;'

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, html, local-storage

hi iam use sessionStorage and store ToBase64String image
but when  use sessionStorage.getItem dont show string .
'char + ' in string convert to '&#x2B;'

```
djF6DFPA56+1RqAAOc07&#x2B;Lr+lK4hz9Bn1qbJ/u1CcDBPT6VIGXaPp6Uho//2Q==
**convert to**
djF6DFPA56&#x2B;1RqAAOc07&#x2B;Lr&#x2B;lK4hz9Bn1qbJ/u1CcDBPT6VIGXaPp6Uho//2Q==
```

Comment: Please show your JavaScript code, it might help to answer.

Comment: do a URI decode and then base64 decode

Comment: Looks like you have a problem in in your input to. Do a URIEncode and then base64 encode and in a similar way decodeUri and then base64 decode. This should give a better idea https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding#Solution_1_%E2%80%93_escaping_the_string_before_encoding_it